# How do I avoid using "the" in a story?

Tags: creative-writing, technique, breaking-the-fourth-wall

No matter what I do, I can't find a way around "the" when it comes to writing stories or making a story that feels like it's repeating. Here's an example of what I've gotten so far with a rewrite I started last week. Keep in mind that I don't have much because I've been busy. The story is about breaking the fourth wall and the main character and the author/narrator coexist in the same universe, sort of like "Stranger Than Fiction" if anyone reading this has seen it.

> “You writing a new story soon?”
>
> “Just started. Well, I mean the draft.”
>
> “What happened to taking a break?”
>
> “I can't just sit there and do nothing.”
>
> “You’re not not doing nothing; you’re taking time to be with a friend.”
>
> “Well, what happened to ‘you writing a new story soon?’”
>
> “******* hell. Can't catch a break now, can I?”
>
> “Not when you keep running your mouth without thinking, and you already agreed to pay for the drinks and the next prescription for my glasses.”
>
> “Look at my luck. My best friend is a book writer and an ***.”
>
> “I'm going home.”
>
> “Bye.”
>
> Arriving home, he puts his things away and prepares to type.
>
> Structural Relation
>
> Jack. A highly intelligent young man, only 19 years and fresh into college. New York is no place for the witty, it’s a city that never sleeps, after all. A haiku freshly spray painted under a bridge on a walk to a certain building, which appeared hidden away from the rest of the world.
>
> “All in the night lights
>
> The city bustles with life
>
> Yet but not without...”
>
> Life. It’s an awkward thing to cope with, to coexist with seven billion others who will never know your story, then there are the others that know you personally and still know nothing about you truly. There will never be anyone who will understand you to the fullest. An old man by the name of Adam declares he’s been everywhere. Such intriguing stories but seemed just as tall at that. A favorite of Jack’s, he visits at noon on the first of every month and enjoys these stories, filled with much detail to a length with the genesis of his life up to retirement and the last journey. Jack’s phone dings violently with messages. 24+ Unread Messages. Scrolling, looking for someone, Noah. 3 Unread Messages.
>
> “Well, looks like I'm popular for once.” he said aloud.
>
> “Jack!”
>
> “Where u at?”
>
> “I’m boreed and need entertainment.”
>
> “I’m about to head to my car”
>
> “Just took a minute to read msgs.”
>
> “I’ll be waiting for u”
>
> “yk I gotta work on my math stuff”
>
> “But youre welcome to come over and make food for me”
>
> “Fine but you’re going to talk to me right?”
>
> “Sure why not”
>
> “Bye”
>
> “Bye ”
>
> Walking back past the mural under the bridge, to an old parking garage, hidden under a tarp and trash bags, A car is dug out. A clever camouflage for a few hours to keep from getting thieved. He packs the tarp in the trunk and clears out. The drive is approximately 12 minutes and the walk from, 10 minutes. Upon arrival, beams of light from the vehicle shine on the corner of the house and Noah walks to the driver's window. The engine cuts off and Noah starts yelling while Jack exits the vehicle.
>
> “Where the hell’ve you been? It’s been like thirty minutes.”
>
> “Traffic, a long walk to my car, and was doing something.”
>
> “I’m sorry I trust you, just couldn’t find the key so I'm just a little pissed.”
>
> “It’s okay, I know how you are, dummy. The key’s in the same place I put it since the house was built, (even though it sucks that it got damaged in the first place) it’s in the broken part of the siding on the wall. Remember, I put it on the block in the wall where the frame of the door is.”
>
> “I don’t think I'd be able to remember that if my life depended on it”
>
> “I’m not moving it.”
>
> “Whatever”
>
> He rolls his eyes and Jack grabs the key to show him,

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the word 'the'? It's a perfectly normal part of English that 99.99% of all books use.

Comment: My problem is overuse. I just want to try a little less of "the".

Comment: You could try reading a bit from [Gadsby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadsby_(novel)) and see how its author does it. There's only 3 "the"s in the whole novel. In fact, there's only 4 "e"s.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. That's what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way: the word 'the' is a rudimentary word of the English language. Like it or not, you kind of *have* to use it sometimes. There are several words that the eye can just glance over easily, hardly paying attention to them. 'The' is one of them.

Don't worry about overusing the word 'the.' Focus your attention on other aspects of storytelling. Repetition of a word so versatile and useful is not a problem whatsoever!

Answer (score 0):

### I don't think you're overusing 'the', I think that you're underusing descriptions.

Take for example this sentence:

> Remember, I put it on the block in the wall where the frame of the door is.

This sentence is as plain as it could possibly be.  None of the items mentioned have any attributes at all.

Worse yet, it has a uniform meter that emphasizes how plain it is

> ...on the **block** in the **wall** where the **frame** of the **door**...

We don't often think of prose as having meter the same way poetry does, but it's always there, and in this particular case it's being felt strongly.  I think, rather than the presence of 'the', what you're noticing is the steady beat of your unadorned sentences.

Compare that to a sentence in a story I was recently reading, [Katalepsis](https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/28023/katalepsis/chapter/418780/mind-correlating-11):

> I put the kettle on while I shuffled into the tiny bathroom to wash out the taste of stomach acid and blood.

If I where to write that sentence in the same style as you used, it would read

> I **put** on the **kettle** while I **walked** to the **bath**room to **wash** out the **taste**.

But a few tweaks ('tiny', 'shuffled' instead of 'walked', and the addition of 'of stomach acid and blood') breaks up the beats and makes the sentence feel a lot less austere.  Even so, I wouldn't want to use this sentence structure too frequently.  Varied sentence structure is the key to making your writing more interesting and comfortable to read, and allows you to control pacing while you're at it.

Try this as an exercise.  Take a sentence of yours (either the one I used above, or a different one), and rewrite it ten times, in different ways.  You're not trying to make it better, just different while saying the same thing.  Break it into two or more sentences, switch it to passive voice, add numerous descriptors, whatever you want.  There is never just one way to say what you want to say, so take control over how you say it.